# Check if child element has same class as parent and remove the child - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In a simple format like below:

```
<div class="par">
    <div class="chl"> Child 1</div>
    <div class="chl"> Child 2</div>

    <div class="par"> Child as Parent 

        <div class="chl"> Child 3</div>
        <div class="chl"> Child 4</div>

    </div>

    <div class="chl"> Child 5</div>

    <div class="par"> Child as Parent 

        <div class="chl"> Child 6</div>
        <div class="chl"> Child 7</div>

    </div>
    <div class="chl"> Child 8</div>
</div>
```

Main `div` with ***par*** class also has some child DIVs which has same class as its parent(***par***). I want to remove the DIVs that has ***par*** class except the main *(I mean the top first)* but leave its children as it is.

Quiet difficult to explain in English, The output I seek is:

```
<div class="par">
    <div class="chl"> Child 1</div>
    <div class="chl"> Child 2</div>

    <div class="chl"> Child 3</div>
    <div class="chl"> Child 4</div>

    <div class="chl"> Child 5</div>

    <div class="chl"> Child 6</div>
    <div class="chl"> Child 7</div>

    <div class="chl"> Child 8</div>
</div>
```

The Divs in beween which has ***par*** class is gone, but the child of those divs are still there.

I wanted to try this with jQuery, but here is some logic I wanted to implement *(I know the code below fails miserably)*, So, I am asking how to achieve this with jQuery.

```
if($('div.par').parent('div.par').has('div.par')) {
    $('div.par').parent('div.par').unwrap();
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z6eu/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.par .par>.chl').unwrap();
```

If you want to remove the text `Child as Parent` then use `contents()` with `filter()`:

```
$('.par').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3    
}).remove();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z6eu/5/)**

Comment: it will remove the top `.par` element too which op doesn't want.

Comment: can you please tell me, what does that `nodeType === 3` does in this case

Comment: @JhilkeDai It's the [.nodeType property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) of the element. This DOM property holds a numeric code indicating the node's type; text nodes use the code 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively easy way to accomplish it:

```
$('.par')                      // find all .par elements
  .children('.par')            // having .par children
  .replaceWith(function() {    // and replace them
    return $(this).children(); // with their own children
  });
```

This avoids having to do another pass to remove the text nodes if you use `unwrap()`.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/pikon/1/)